# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell" & linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: iphone, ios

I've downloaded a sample source code from https://github.com/mattdonnelly/MDAudioPlayerController, but when I open in Xcode version 4.52  that, I'm getting the error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell", referenced from:objc-class-ref in MDAudioPlayerController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

```
Ld /Users/fastpwr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MDAudioPlayerSample-cyywpdxygeoqowdjhtaosupvdbns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDAudioPlayerSample.app/MDAudioPlayerSample normal i386
cd "/Users/fastpwr/Downloads/MDAudioPlayerController-master-1/Sample App"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Users/fastpwr/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/fastpwr/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Users/fastpwr/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Users/fastpwr/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/fastpwr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MDAudioPlayerSample-cyywpdxygeoqowdjhtaosupvdbns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/fastpwr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MDAudioPlayerSample-cyywpdxygeoqowdjhtaosupvdbns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/fastpwr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MDAudioPlayerSample-cyywpdxygeoqowdjhtaosupvdbns/Build/Intermediates/MDAudioPlayerSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDAudioPlayerSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/MDAudioPlayerSample.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework CoreMIDI -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreData -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/fastpwr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MDAudioPlayerSample-cyywpdxygeoqowdjhtaosupvdbns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDAudioPlayerSample.app/MDAudioPlayerSample![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: I try this but my sample code it does not work, kindly check it out...

Comment: Any one download sample code and check its error or not. If not kindly check it out...?